# Error displaying Admob banner in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, admob

I'm familiar with implementing Admobs within my app, however im struggling with changing my code from Activities to Fragments.

I'm getting a NullPointerException. I believe using getView() may be causing my issue.

## Admob code: Fragment

```
//CREATE BANNER ADD
    private void createAdmobBanner() 
    {
        // Create an ad.

        adView = (com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView) getView()
                .findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

        // Add a test device to show Test Ads
                 .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                // .addTestDevice("B3827F13FB335337F4CA0F350B78A866")
                        .build();


                // Load ads into Banner Ads
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
```

## XML Admob Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adViewHolder"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/ad_bottom_height"
android:layout_marginTop="1dp"

android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxx/xxxx"
  />

</LinearLayout>


 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_height"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Refresh Scores"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:textSize="11dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
      />
```

**Note:** I use ...include layout="@layout/admob_ad" /> in my fragment layout xml.

## Code Error:

09-24 22:04:02.429: E/AndroidRuntime(5375): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void   com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
09-24 22:04:02.429: E/AndroidRuntime(5375):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.ChampionsFragment.createAdmobBanner(ChampionsFragment.java:391)

Answer (score 0):

I faced Similar issue, when i checked closely in resourse file
There were two resourse file for my activity:

1. `\res\layout\activity_main_lauch.xml`
2. `\res\layout-v21\activity_main_lauch.xml`

I was modifing single file, hence it was throwing error. when i apply the change in both files it started working.